# How to store a password as BCRYPT in a database as '$2a$15' in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, bcrypt

I am wondering on how to store passwords as `BCRYPT` that starts with `$2a$15`, because I have already setup my register and it already stores the passwords in `BCRYPT`.

However, when it stores the passwords as `BCRYPT`, the output is `$2y$15`, but I want it as `$2a$15`. I am new to `BCRYPT` and I find it quite hard to understand.

Anyway, here is my `BCRYPT` code:

```
function encryptedPassword($strPassword) {
    $strSHA256 = hash('sha256', $strPassword);
    $strBcrypt = password_hash($strSHA256, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 15, 'salt' => bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12))));
    return $strBcrypt;
}
```

So, say if my password is `Hello123!`. The output of that would be:

```
$2y$15$aa979703a103b0a45b2afO0KS15RjWu5Lc8sa4.xQlsw9QLtyhp/O
```

and I want it to be:

```
$2a$15$aa979703a103b0a45b2afO0KS15RjWu5Lc8sa4.xQlsw9QLtyhp/O
```

I don't know if this is to do with the salt, can someone help me?

Comment: 1. Why do you want it as `$2a$` specifically? 2. Why are you hashing the password with SHA256 before bcrypt?! 3. Why are you generating your own salt?!

Comment: 4. Why aren't you using `password_hash()` and its companion `password_verify()`?

Comment: 5. Why is that function called "encryptedPassword" when it's *hashing* the password?

Comment: The answers to these questions, and more, on tonight's episode of "Why I Shouldn't Build My Own Authentication Layer"!

Comment: Followed by another episode of "Help, I got hacked!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP manual:

> PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash.
>   This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$"
>   identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE
>   on failure.

So using BCRYPT will always produce $2y$. By the way, the begining part of the hash is just an identifier, used for testing the password afterwards with password_verify. Just like the $15$ in your case being the cost of the hashing algorithm...

I suggest you read more on PHP password hashing. There is absolutely no sane reason why you'd want a hash to absolutely start with X or Y...

The PHP folks have put great efforts on giving you secure password hashing functions. You should really try using them without hacking stuff around it. hashing a hash is no safer than just hashing once. The salt option is deprecated in PHP7, I'd suggest you get rid of it, PHP can handle it better than you.

Comment: Alright, thank you for this information. I guess I need to do a bit more research about something before asking a question about it aha.